# Communication on the boundary of a $C^1$ domain

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, analytic-geometry

Assume $\Omega$ is a $C^1$ bounded domain of $\mathbb{R}^d$, $d \geq 2$. For $(x,y) \in (\partial \Omega)^2$, we say $x \sim y$ if $n_x \cdot (y-x) > 0$, $n_y \cdot (x-y) > 0$, and $(tx+(1-t)y) \in \Omega$ for all $t \in (0,1)$.

Is it true that for any $(x,y) \in (\partial \Omega)^2$ such that $x \sim y$, one can find $\epsilon_1 > 0, \epsilon_2 > 0$ such that $(B(x,\epsilon_1) \cap \partial \Omega) \sim (B(y,\epsilon_2) \cap \partial \Omega)$ (in the sense that for any $a \in (B(x,\epsilon_1) \cap \partial \Omega)$, $b \in B(y,\epsilon_2) \cap \partial \Omega)$, $a \sim b$)?

From the $C^1$ property of the domain it seems clear that for all $(x,y) \in \partial \Omega^2$ with $x \sim y$, one can find $\epsilon > 0$ such that $x \sim B(y,\epsilon) \cap \partial \Omega$ (and I have a proof for it). However the stronger result that I ask, although I don't see any reason why this should not hold, puzzles me a lot more.

Any idea whether the statement is true ? And how to show it ?

Comment: In the second paragraph, do you mean for any $(x,y)$ such that $x \sim y$? If I understand you definition correctly, if $\Omega$ is convex, then $x \sim y$ for any two points on the boundary?

Comment: Of course ! Thank you, I have corrected it. Actually $x \sim y$ for any two points on the boundary if $\Omega$ is strictly convex, not with the sole convex assumption (a square for instance will not satisfy this). However convex + $C^1$ is probably enough.

Comment: @Gâteau-Gallois: In the 3rd paragraph, do you also mean to say "for all $x,y \in \partial \Omega$ *with $x \sim y$*"?

Comment: Absolutely, thanks, I will correct this.